# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve | Vue Router

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-router, laravel-7

I am new to vue and laravel. I am trying to import my component but I am getting this error.

**ERROR in ./resources/js/router.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './pages/frontend/HomepageComponent'**

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import HomepageComponent from './pages/frontend/HomepageComponent'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
{
    path: '/',
    component: HomepageComponent
}
]

export default new VueRouter({
    routes
})
```

I searched everywhere but I am not being able to figure out how to solve this issue.

Please help me.

Comment: did you verify the component name `HomepageComponent.vue` ?

Comment: And is `HomepageComponent.vue` located on `/resources/js/pages/frontend/` directory?

Comment: Yes, the name is fine as well as the location.

Comment: could you share the HomepageComponent file too, please?

Comment: It shows the error in the **router.js** file:
**import HomepageComponent from './pages/frontend/HomepageComponent'**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding .vue to your import of the file

import HomepageComponent from './pages/frontend/HomepageComponent'

so it looks like:

import HomepageComponent from './pages/frontend/HomepageComponent.vue'

If I'm not wrong, the import will by default look for a .js file extension, so you have to be specific that you are looking for a .vue file.

EDIT: Solution was unrelated to the answer above, the problem was a typo in the components file name.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the code in your HomepageComponent and another screenshot of your folder and file structure?

Comment: The code to my resources files is in this [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/21232af21ea5c716992af334b68351e120200512062534/8a2b9a)

I also found that my error is in HomepageComponent.vue because it works fine when I replace HomepageComponent with ExampleComponent.

Comment: Uh, I think this boils down to a typo in your files friend. Your HomepageComponent file is misspelled "HompageComponent" missing the "e" in "Home"

Answer (score 10):

Run Command

```
npm install --save vue-router
```

Answer (score 4):

I resolved the problem with

```
npm install --save vue-router
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved by creating another folder under **assets** folder and moving components there.