# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './router'| Vue router

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

in search.js from this file:

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from "vue-router";

import SearchIndex from './components/omdb/SearchIndex.vue'

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'welcome',
        component: SearchIndex
    },
]

export default createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})
```

in app.js from this file:

```
require('./bootstrap');

require('alpinejs');

import { createApp } from "vue";
import router from './router'
import SearchIndex from './components/omdb/SearchIndex'


createApp({
    components:{
        SearchIndex
    }
}).use(router).mount('#app')
```

this error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js 6:0-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './router' in 'D:\xampp\htdocs\omdb\resources\js'
```

I don't understand why it gives me this error. I structured the file as follows:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve | Vue Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61731019/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-vue-router)

Comment: unfortunately I have not already launched the "npm install --save vue-router
" command but it has not solved. i don't understand how i can't compile the folder is there

Comment: Try modifying the path in search.js as
`import SearchIndex from '../components/omdb/SearchIndex.vue'`

Comment: i have same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module path in `import router from './router'` resolves to either `./router.js` or `./router/index.js`. Neither file exists, leading to the error you observed.

You can either rename `./router/search.js` to `./router/index.js`, or import the `./router/search.js` file directly:

```js
import router from './router/search'
```